# how to execute javascript code after content disposition of a file

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a problem executing javascript code after content disposition of a csv file. I want to know what im doing wrong and what is the solution. My code is like this

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
//below line is not executing
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Report), "asdfs", "alert('test')");
```